# How to read conflicted UIDocument from unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:

Tags: ios, merge, icloud, conflict, uidocument

When Conflict occur in UIDocument I can get all conflicted version by calling `unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:` on `NSFileVersion` but how can I get UIDocument (snapshot) of that versions ?

I want to loop all versions and merge it myself.

**Updated**
I have come across this [How can I merge conflicted UIDocument's in iCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14885404/147564) and try to do it this way, but I don't think its correct one because open UIDocument is asynchronous operation. What is the right way to do this ?

```
    NSFileVersion *currentVersion = [NSFileVersion currentVersionOfItemAtURL:senderDocument.fileURL];
    NSArray *conflictedVersions = [NSFileVersion unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:senderDocument.fileURL];
    RecentDocument *currentDocument = [[RecentDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:currentVersion.URL];
    [currentDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open");
            return ;
        }
        for (NSFileVersion *version in conflictedVersions) {
            RecentDocument *conflictedDocument = [[RecentDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:version.URL];
            [conflictedDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if (!success) {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to open");
                    return ;
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: What does `UIDocument` opening being asynchronous have to do with it? `NSFileVersion` is how you find the conflict versions, and `UIDocument` is how you open them (if you need to open them). If you want more detail see the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12837/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-4).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: How can I merge conflicted UIDocument's in iCloud?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885404/ios-how-can-i-merge-conflicted-uidocuments-in-icloud)

Comment: In my sample code, I got all NSFileVersion conflicts, but to read its content(to merge data myself) I have to open it which is asynchronous operation. In the link its teach you how to show conflict manually which isn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling openWithCompletionHandler, you want to do something along the lines of:

```
RecentDocument * thisDoc = [[RecentDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
NSError* innerReadError;
[thisDoc readFromURL:url error:&innerReadError];
```

So swap openWithCompletionHandler with readFromURL and you should be able to access your document right away in order to resolve the conflict.